# Verifying permissions on S3 object in Ruby

Tags: ruby, permissions, amazon-s3, acl

I'm using [aws-sdk for Ruby](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby) to manage objects on S3. I'm able grant public read permissions by setting

```
object.acl = :public_read
```

Is there a way to determine if there is already public read permission granted to the object before doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby aws-sdk has poor documentation, and I wasn't able to locate it as well. Below is a function that I have created to check whether a file has read permission or not. Modify it as per your needs:

```
 def check_if_public_read(object)
    object.acl.grants.each do |grant|
      begin
        if(grant.grantee.uri == "http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers")
          return true if ([:read, :full_control].include?(grant.permission.name))
        end
      rescue
      end
    end
    return false
  end
```

where object is any S3 Object:

```
 AWS.config(
    :access_key_id     => "access key",
    :secret_access_key => "secret key"
  )
  s3 = AWS::S3.new

file = s3.buckets["my_bucket"].objects["path/to/file.png"]

check_if_public_read(file) => true
```

Please note that I have figured this out looking at the objects and aws-sdk source code, and the uri parameter may change over time. This works now, and for aws-sdk gem version 1.3.5.